# Custom loop to query posts with no featured image and/or no post editor content

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am looking to query and pull a list of all custom posts 'foo' that have no featured image set and/or have no text copy (from the WP editor).  The list will be used to determine which posts need content and/or a featured image.  (We're importing a huge database from an outside source).

I'm starting with this-

```
$result = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'post_type' => 'foo' ) );
```

How would I change this to 1) *exclude* any post with a featured images set [I realize as it is now it includes them] and 2) also exclude any post that has content in the post editor?

Answer (score 1):

Featured image part is easy enough, you know what custom field is called, you just need to tweak it a bit for `NOT EXISTS` condition for it, see [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex.

Empty content is harder, that is not something `WP_Query` does. However in SQL it should be easy (content field equals empty string or along those lines) so you could run custom query via `wpdb` for that condition or add it via filter to `WP_Query` (which is probably overkill unless you really need these combined together, doesn't seem it's that important from description).